How to create a sharepoint group to allow view, but not download?
When I share a folder, I can choose whether the end user can edit, or view, or view (but not download).
How can I achieve this using permissions in SharePoint? I mean can I create a sharepoint group with view only permission and no download?

Yes, you can do it using group and view only permissions.
